# Examples of bilimits that aren't 2-limits, and some related questions

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

Recently I've received an email from Sori Lee about an [earlier question I had asked](https://mathoverflow.net/q/386414), and we ended up with a number of questions about 2-limits and 2-bilimits which I couldn't quite answer, and decided to ask here.

Throughout this question let XXX = lax, oplax, strong/pseudo, or strict.

The first question that came up was the following:

> What is an example of an XXX bilimit that isn't an XXX $2$-limit.

The first potential example that came to my mind would be the following: the $2$-limit of the empty diagram in the $2$-category $\mathsf{Cats}$ of categories, functors, and natural transformations would be the punctual category $\mathsf{pt}$ having a single object and a single (identity) morphism, whereas *I think* any contractible groupoid would serve as the $2$-bilimit of that diagram.

**Question 1.** Is this correct? More generally, if we have a diagram $D$ in a bicategory $\mathcal{C}$ with $2$-limit $\mathsf{2lim}(D)$ and an object $L$ of $\mathcal{C}$ equivalent to $\mathsf{2lim}(D)$, must $L$ be a 2-bilimit of $D$? If not, is there a useful criterion for when this is the case?

**Question 2.** Are there any examples (especially naturally occurring) of bicategories that are co/complete with respect to all XXX $2$-bilimits, but not with respect to all XXX $2$-limits?

**Question 3.** Lax/oplax/pseudo $W$-weighted $2$-limits can be seen as special cases of strict $Q(W)$-weighted $2$-limits where $Q(W)$ is a lax/oplax/pseudo morphism classifier. Is the same true if we replace "$2$-limits" with "$2$-bilimits"?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want a strict weighted bilimit to be, actually. It classifies strictly 2-natural cones (cylinders)? But it doesn't really even make sense to look at strictly 2-natural cones over anything but a strict 2-functor, right? So to have any hope for something like that to be true you'd have to first make sure you could strictify the diagram you wanted a limit of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q1. Yes, every object that is equivalent to a bicategorical limit is again a bicategorical limit. This is easy to deduce from the definition. It can also be deduced from the corresponding fact about representable pseudofunctors.

Q2. The 2-category of monoidal categories has a bicategorical initial object $\{1\}$, but no $2$-categorical initial object. Otherwise, $\{1\}$ would be $2$-categorical initial, i.e. the category of monoidal functors $\{1\} \to \mathcal{C}$ would be isomorphic to the terminal category $\star$ for all $\mathcal{C}$. But this is not the case:

It is well-known that the lax monoidal functors $\{1\} \to \mathcal{C}$ are monoid objects $(M,m,e)$ in $\mathcal{C}$. The functor is strong monoidal iff $e : 1 \to M$ and $m : M \otimes M \to M$ are isomorphisms. It follows that the category of strong monoidal functors is isomorphic to the category of isomorphisms $1 \to M$. This is clearly equivalent to $\star$, but not isomorphic to $\star$, since there are many isomorphisms $1 \to M$.

Essentially, the notion of isomorphism of categories is often too strict.

A more interesting example: In the $2$-category of cocomplete symmetric monoidal categories (this includes the condition that $\otimes$ is cocontinuous in each variable), $(\mathbf{Set},\times)$ is bicategorical initial, but there is no $2$-categorical initial object. If $R$ is a commutative ring, then $(\mathbf{Mod}_R,\otimes)$ is bicategorical (and not $2$-categorical) initial in the $2$-category of cocomplete symmetric monoidal $R$-linear categories.

If $X,Y$ are two quasi-compact quasi-separated $R$-schemes, then $\mathbf{Qcoh}(X \times_R Y)$ is the bicategorical coproduct of $\mathbf{Qcoh}(X)$ and $\mathbf{Qcoh}(Y)$ in the $2$-category of cocomplete symmetric monoidal $R$-linear categories (this is the main result of [Localizations of tensor categories and fiber products of schemes](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.00383)), but there will not be any $2$-categorical coproduct.

Another simple example: consider the $2$-category of categories with coproducts (or small categories with finite coproducts, this also works) and functors preserving coproducts. Here, the coproduct of a family $(\mathcal{C}_i)_{i \in I}$ is the subcategory of $\prod_{i \in I} \mathcal{C}_i$ consisting of those objects $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ such that almost all $x_i$ are initial. (This is a categorification of the construction of coproducts of abelian groups.) In fact, if $\mathcal{D}$ is a category with coproducts, then there is an *equivalence* of categories (the $\sqcup$ subscript indicates coproduct-preserving functors)
$$\textstyle\hom_{\sqcup}(\coprod_{i \in I} \mathcal{C}_i,\mathcal{D}) \simeq \prod_{i \in I} \hom_{\sqcup}(\mathcal{C}_i,\mathcal{D}).$$
But there is no isomorphism, so again there is no $2$-categorical coproduct.

Comment: PS: I prefer the term "bicategorical limit" instead of "bilimit", because it is more explicit and cannot be confused with other notions where "bi" stands for "twosided".

Comment: Nice clear counterexamples — and perhaps worth adding that your example for Q2 is a very typical kind of example: in 2-categories of “categories with structure”, whose maps preserve that structure not-necessarily-on-the-nose, the colimits will generally be only bicategorical not strictly 2-categorical.

Comment: Very interesting; am I mistaken, or is your example a non-circular $2$-categorical characterization of the category of sets with Cartesian products? I say non-circular because I’ve seen it [argued](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379029/is-bf-set-the-terminal-autological-topos) that characterizations like ‘the terminal Grothendieck  topos’ are circular because the definition of a Grothendieck topos involves the category of sets, but that doesn’t seem to be the case here. (maybe in the cocompleteness condition?)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Wow, I was expecting there might be only artificial examples for Q2, but the examples you mentioned are \*so\* nice. Thank you for the answer, Martin! :)

Comment: I hope that someone else can answer Q3. I saw that you accepted my answer, even though I didn't answer Q3. Maybe ask a separate question?

Comment: You’re obviously considering a $2$-category of locally small categories if ${\bf Set}$ is a member of your $2$-category; ignoring the foundational issues because I’m sure you know how to remedy them, you’re also sweeping the word ‘small’ under the rug when you say cocomplete, no?

Comment: Yes my (quite standard) conventions are: All categories are locally small unless otherwise stated. Cocomplete means the existence of small colimits.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Convention within a discipline can be confusing to people not already familiar with it; in a setting like this with potentially thousands of readers in the years to come (not all of whom will have the same ‘standard conventions’ as you), I believe it’s best to be as explicit as possible. More to the point, perhaps there is hidden circularity in your characterization in light of the fact that the colimit size condition makes reference to being an object of the category of sets. Still cool!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg It's hard not to accept the answer when it's so good =) As Kevin noted though, there seems to be some problems with how Q3 is currently formulated, and since I haven't thought about bilimits and the topics surrounding then in a long long time, I think I'll try reading a bit about them and see if I can rephrase Q3 in a way that makes sense. If that goes well I'll then ask it as a separate question :) Thank you so much again, Martin!

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to flesh out Martin's nice concrete examples to **Question 2** a bit with a more general perspective. As with the 2-category of monoidal categories and strong or lax monoidal functors, basically every 2-category of structured categories and pseudo morphisms will be bicategorically complete and cocomplete but not 2-categorically so. This includes 2-categories like the 2-category of categories admitting $J$-shaped limits or colimits and functors preserving the same as well as various relatives of monoidal categories, and quite generally, the 2-categories of algebras and pseudo-morphisms for any 2-monad $T$ on 2-categories such as those of categories or of multicategories.

These 2-categories, as well as strict 2-initial or 2-terminal objects, lack strict (co)equalizers, pullbacks, and pushouts. For a simple example, let $\star$ be the terminal category and $I$ the category freely generated by an isomorphism. These are both trivial examples of categories with finite products, and both functors $\star\rightrightarrows I$ preserve these products (for instance, because they are equivalences of categories.) But not only does this diagram have no equalizer, there is *no* object whatsoever in the 2-category of categories with finite products that strictly equalizes these two morphisms! This behavior is quite typical; note that however $\star$ is the equalizer of this diagram in the bicategorical sense.

A good keyword for learning more on this topic is "PIE": a 2-category admitting the specific set Products, Inserters, and Equifiers of weighted 2-limits is always bicategorically complete.

As for **Question 3**, I commented on the main post that I'm not quite sure that a strict weighted bicategorical limit is a well-defined notion. However certainly it's true that pseudo- lax- and oplax-limits, in the bicategorical sense, can also be given in terms of weighted limits (themselves defined in the pseudo sense.) I think I would approach this by observing that not only does every bicategory have a *strictification*, i.e. an equivalent 2-category, but it has a *continuously* equivalent 2-category, namely its image under the bicategorical Yoneda embedding, which is a complete 2-category for which the Yoneda embedding preserves whatever limits exist. So you can convert, say, a bicategorical pseudolimit to a weighted one by converting the corresponding 2-categorical pseudolimit to a weighted one under the Yoneda embedding.

Comment: 2-categories whose 1-morphisms are lax morphisms between structured categories usually aren't bicategorically complete or cocomplete. For example, given a monoidal category $C$ and a monoid $m$ in $C$, the co-slice category $m/C$ doesn't admit in general a monoidal structure making it the (bicategorical) lax limit of the arrow $m \colon 1 \to C$ in the 2-category of monoidal categories and lax monoidal functors.

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Oh, interesting, I guess I had never actually thought this through beyond the pseudo case. Yes, I suppose you more or less need your monoid operation to be invertible to get a monoidal coslice…At least in return for this public mistake I get to take away some natural examples of non-representable multicategories I hadn’t noticed before!

Comment: @KevinArlin Thank you so much for the answer, Kevin! This perspective on completeness with respect to bilimits vs. 2-limits is so nice! On Q3, it's been ages since I've done anything with bilimits actually, I think I'll try reading about them again and see if I can rephrase it into a question that makes sense. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Emily Thanks for the kind words.